# Update Ajax Toolkit Slider extender with jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, slider

I need some help please

This is the HTML CODE GENERATED BY THE TOOLKIT EXTENDER

```
          <td width="16px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ModInsteon1$6$Slider1" type="text" value="100" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ModInsteon1$6$Slider1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_Slider1" style="font-size:Smaller;" />

                <span id="MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_lblvalue" style="font-size:Small;"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_Td1" colspan="2">
                <span id="MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_lblDeviceName" style="display:inline-block;font-size:Smaller;width:100%;">X10 Lamp</span>
            </td>
```

Now I have a jQuery function that needs to update the slider value.

Unfortunately I can only update the `TEXT` element - which does not trigger the updates..

```
$("#MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_Slider1").val(message);
```

The textbox (which is not shown) gets updated, but the value of the slider is still 0 and the slider does not move. Any ideas?

Comment: What precisely is the question? What happens if you update the value as you've done here?

Answer (score 0):

Call to `val()` usually don't fire `change` event. Try to raise it yourself:

```
  $("#MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_Slider1").val(message).change();
```

Depending on the slider implementation, you might need to raise a different event to trigger synchronization, e.g.

```
  $("#MainContent_ModInsteon1_6_Slider1").val(message).keyup();
```